Omitting the subject in German? Hegel
Below is a quote about Hobbes from Hegel’s History of Philosophy. I don’t undstand the bolded part. The plural verb sind seems to refer to Gedanken, but the comparative als seems to be introducing something new that the “gesündere Gedanken” are better than.
For example if the last part reads as “gesündere Gedanken, als die, die zum Teil noch im Umlauf sind“ it would make a lot more sense to me. Is Hegel omitting a word in that last phrase? Is that allowed?

Er sagt ferner: Was die staatsrechtliche Philosophie (philosopbia civilis) betreffe, so sei sie nicht älter als sein Buch De cive.1 Dies (Paris 1642) ist, wie auch sein Leviathan, ein sehr verrufenes Werk; dieses letzte Buch war verboten und ist daher selten. Sie enthalten über die Natur der Gesellschaft und der Regierung gesündere Gedanken, als zum Teil noch im Umlauf sind.



Sie enthalten über die Natur der Gesellschaft und der Regierung gesündere Gedanken, als zum Teil noch im Umlauf sind.

It helps to first analyze the main sentence:

Sie enthalten über die Natur der Gesellschaft und der Regierung gesündere Gedanken

So, they contain healtier thoughts about the nature of society and government. But "healthier" is a comparative and this begs the question "healthier - compared to what?"
The answer is in the relative sentence: compared to what is now being circulated. "In Umlauf (sein)" is a fixed phrase meaning (being) in circulation. The phrase is regularly issued in the context of money:

Derzeit ist Falschgeld im Umlauf.

Counterfeit money is currently in circulation.
In the context of thoughts about the nature of society and government this simply means: they are being (widely?) discussed. So the whole sentence means:

They contain healthier thoughts than are being circulated right now about the nature of society and government.


The relevant phrase is

gesündere Gedanken(,) als zum Teil noch im Umlauf sind.

healthier thoughts than those that are partly still in circulation.
(That comma would be omitted in modern German. That for the reason that the last part is a comparison and not an adverbial clause. The comma can lead to confusion about that because als is also a subordinating conjunction.)
Such comparisons of noun phrases with clauses are somewhat common in German. And yeah, you could rewrite it to match the English phrasing more closely.

gesündere Gedanken(,) als die, die zum Teil noch im Umlauf sind.

But that's not needed in German.
